# I simply need to upload a jar file to Jenkins Cloudbees, I can't do it?

Tags: jenkins, salesforce, cloudbees

I just need to copy a file from my local machine to Cloudbees (in /opt/ant/latest/lib or in /home/jenkins/.ant/lib). I Tried to connect via finder using thie method: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Sharing+Files+with+Build+Executors, But Finder tells me to check the server or IP address. I really checked my username and password though.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you access https://repository-{account-id}.forge.cloudbees.com/private/ from browser with your username and password?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebDav client like Cyberduck. You can see how to do the configuration [here](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Deploying+released+artifacts+from+CloudBees+DEV%40cloud+to+external+Maven+Repositories) -0. Pre-requisites.